# Scheduling and rescheduling emails

Tags: logic

Background

A workflow I have allows users to book meetings. The time/day of the meeting is stored in a table along with other details like the email address.

I send them an email reminder 30 minutes in advance.

Problem

In order to send them an email, a recurring event is set up once a week to go through the table and schedule the email to be sent on time - 30 minutes.

I've added the ability to reschedule the meeting. The problem that creates is that the emails are already scheduled, so users get the reminders at the original time, which is confusing.

What I want to do

I want to be able to send them the email at the rescheduled time, but there are technical limitations to the platform I use, which are:

1. I cannot set up cron/recurring more frequently than every day. This would probably be better than every week, but if someone rescheduled within the day, they would still get the wrong email.
2. I cannot remove scheduled events - so any recurring events-based workflow would still send the original email.

I know - this is pretty limiting, but am I even approaching this in the right way?

Answer (score 0):

given your constraints, I'd probably go with 'resign'.

But in all seriousness, if you can't remove scheduled events (and I'm guessing you can't 'move' them because this is too advanced for your CTO to get their head around) then the only way I see it is to break the email send process into two steps - send scheduled event to PROXY in-front of your email sender, check if there is another event (i.e. can you add some 'cancelled/moved to data to the original one) and if so don't send it.